# DBunit data is not visible in Oracle

Tags: junit, junit4, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit, springjunit4classrunner

In my project we are using xml files to insert data into Database(oracle).But, I am not getting where this data is inserted in DB.I am seeing insert statements while executing query. But data is not visible in DB. While retrieving, the data is coming from DB. But where this data is stored in DB. It is using any temporary tables to store data in DB or any other mechanism it is using. I debugged the code while executing the insert query statement.Insert query statement is executed successfully.But data is not visible in DB.

Please explain me if any one has idea on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not committing the data into DB. If you wont commit the data you cannot see the data in Database.